# Update-Module not finding PSGallery repo in script as a scheduled task

Tags: powershell

I have a scheduled task which runs an exported function from my PowerShell module which is hosted at [powershellgallery.com](https://powershellgallery.com). The function performs a check against the built-in PSGallery repository to see if a newer version is available and if so, update it.

I've noticed my module is not being updated as it should and to troubleshoot the issue I've redirected the output from two separate commands. First, to make sure the repository is 'visible' to the `SYSTEM` account running the task I run:

```
Get-PSRepository *>> c:\repo.log
```

This yields the following output:

> Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
>   ----                      ------------------   --------------
>   PSGallery                 Untrusted            https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2

So the `SYSTEM` account running the function as a scheduled task can 'see' the repo; no problem. Next, the function runs the `Update-Module` command as such:

```
Update-Module -Name $ProductName -Confirm:$false -Force -Verbose *>> c:\update.log
```

This yields the following output:

> Checking for updates for module '[removed by me]'.
>   PackageManagement\Install-Package : Unable to find repository 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/'. Use 
>   Get-PSRepository to see all available repositories.
>   At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.0.4\PSModule.psm1:12546 char:20
>   + ...           $sid = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
>   +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex 
>      ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SourceNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

Lastly, I checked the module to make sure it is indeed associated with `PSGallery` by running:

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name $ProductName | fl
```

The output shows:

> RepositorySourceLocation   : https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/
>
> Repository                 : PSGallery

UPDATE: I decided to use the `Install-Module` with the `-Force` switch to 'update' the module instead as I couldn't get the other command to work. Oddly though, when I do a `Get-InstalledModule -AllVersions` I can clearly see a difference between a module installed interactively and one installed under the `SYSTEM` account (running as a scheduled task). Pay attention to the `Repository` column:

[image: PowerShell Repo]

1. If I run the function interactively it works without issue.
2. If I run `Find-Module -Name $ProductName` from within the function it finds the module without issue.
3. Tried both solutions from [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358723/unable-to-find-repository-on-update-module) to no avail...

Any idea why the `Update-Module` command can't find the repo??

Comment: Potential duplicate of (Unable to find repository on Update-Module) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358723/unable-to-find-repository-on-update-module

Comment: Thank you but those answers were attempted as well. I'll update my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are seeing the bug described in https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues/349 . It's not really related to SYSTEM account. Simplest workaround until fixed version is released is to uninstall the module then reinstall it again. You should only have to do that once, and update-module should work thereafter.

**UPDATE:** This is resolved in newer builds of PowerShellGet.

Comment: Great find! Welcome to SO :)

Comment: Thanks for the update Edwin! If you don't mind I've edited that into your answer so it doesn't get lost in a comment purge.