# Powershell - Not able to find module

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I'm experiencing problems when (re)installing modules in PowerShell (see Screenshot link below). It has worked before as the module is already installed.

[Screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lejF.png)

Already tried the following:

- Set-ExecutionPolicy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6
- .Net Framework 4.7.2 is already installed: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Unable-to-Connect-with-Power-BI-Service-using-PowerShell/td-p/483356
- Repository change: [Unable to find repository on Update-Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358723/unable-to-find-repository-on-update-module)

I'm out of ideas / Google results. Any suggestions/ideas that I can try? Many thanks in advance.

Error in text:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt
WARNING: Source Location 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt/1.0.840' is not valid.
PackageManagement\Install-Package : Package 'MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt' failed to download.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1772 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (C:\Users\admin....werBIMgmt.nupkg:String) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PackageFailedInstallOrDownload,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

Best regards

Comment: It says [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Workspaces/1.0.840) you should install using `Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Workspaces`

Comment: [Rollup module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt) says to install it exactly as Jorn tried.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have outdated version of `PowerShellGet` 1.0.0.1. Try this first (as admin) and then retry your update.

```bsh
Update-Module PowerShellGet
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

An update didn't work because it wasn't installed by using Install-Module. So I tried Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force, I get exactly the same error as for the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt module.

So seems an issue with internet or some config in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this

`[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`